# Android: custom AlertDialog not wraps content correctly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-alertdialog

I have a problem with a custom `AlertDialog` layout params i'm not able to solve. So, please, helpe me.

This is the AlertDialog layout (inputqty_dialog.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp" >

   <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" >

    <TextView
        style="@style/Label"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAA AA AAAAAAAA"/>

    <EditText
        style="@style/EditText"
        android:id="@+id/inputQtyDlg_qtyTxt"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"/>


  </LinearLayout>


  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" >


    <TextView
        style="@style/Label"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="@string/label_MAX_QTY"/>

    <EditText
        style="@style/EditText"
        android:id="@+id/inputQtyDlg_maxQtyTxt"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>

  </LinearLayout>


  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" >

    <TextView
        style="@style/Label"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="AAAA AAAA A AAAAAAAAAA"/>

    <EditText
        style="@style/EditText"
        android:id="@+id/inputQtyDlg_requiredQtyTxt"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>

  </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the code i use to inflate it:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
View dialog_layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inputqty_dialog, null);
builder .setTitle(getArguments().getString("message"))
                .setView(dialog_layout));
```

And this is the orrible result i get:

[image]

As you can see i have set `wrap_content` overall in layout file but `AlertDialog` overlooks that params and cuts the dialog not wrapping the content correctly. How can i solve? Thank you

Comment: thats means that are you want to show alert dialog in full screen??

Comment: I want that my dialog wraps its content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set minHeight to your edittext,

```
 <EditText
        style="@style/EditText"
        android:id="@+id/inputQtyDlg_qtyTxt"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `minHeight="Xdp"` to the root `LinearLayout` is a possible solution, but is not THE solution..